# Setting up a kerberized HA NFS share

Tags: nfs, kerberos, high-availability, nfsv4

I'm trying to set up a kerberized NFS share from an HA cluster. I've successfully set up a krb-aware NFS share from a single server, I'm using a mostly identical configuration on the cluster.

Exports file from working single server:

```
/nfs    *(rw,sec=krb5:krb5i:krb5p)
```

Cluster resource configuration:

```
# pcs resource show nfs-export1
 Resource: nfs-export1 (class=ocf provider=heartbeat type=exportfs)
  Attributes: clientspec=10.1.0.0/255.255.255.0 directory=/nfsshare/exports/export1 fsid=1 options=rw,sec=krb5:krb5i:krb5p,sync,no_root_squash
  Operations: monitor interval=10 timeout=20 (nfs-export1-monitor-interval-10)
              start interval=0s timeout=40 (nfs-export1-start-interval-0s)
              stop interval=0s timeout=120 (nfs-export1-stop-interval-0s)
```

Client `showmount` to working single server:

```
# showmount -e ceserv
Export list for ceserv:
/nfs *
```

Client `showmount` to floating cluster name:

```
# showmount -e hafloat
Export list for hafloat:
/nfsshare/exports/export1 10.1.0.0/255.255.255.0
/nfsshare/exports         10.1.0.0/255.255.255.0
```

Contents of client `/etc/fstab`:

```
ceserv:/nfs /mnt/nfs nfs4 sec=krb5i,rw,proto=tcp,port=2049
hafloat.ncphotography.lan:export1 /nfsmount nfs4 sec=krb5i,rw,proto=tcp,port=2049
```

Results of `mount -av` command:

```
# mount -av
mount.nfs4: timeout set for Mon Dec  4 20:57:14 2017
mount.nfs4: trying text-based options 'sec=krb5i,proto=tcp,port=2049,vers=4.1,addr=10.1.0.24,clientaddr=10.1.0.23'
/mnt/nfs                 : successfully mounted
mount.nfs4: timeout set for Mon Dec  4 20:57:14 2017
mount.nfs4: trying text-based options 'sec=krb5i,proto=tcp,port=2049,vers=4.1,addr=10.1.0.29,clientaddr=10.1.0.23'
mount.nfs4: mount(2): Operation not permitted
mount.nfs4: Operation not permitted
```

All firewalls have been disabled. All names resolve correctly to IP addresses within the 10.1.0.0/24 network, and all IP addresses reverse-resolve to the correct hostname.